# How do the Mariner and Luremaster professions work in Multiplayer?

Tags: stardew-valley

The Mariner and Luremaster professions in Stardew Valley concern crab pots, making them produce no trash or require no bait, respectively.

But in multiplayer, how do they work? Do only the crab pots placed by the player with the profession have that bonus, or does simply having one player in the server with that profession grants all crab pots the bonus?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Professions in multiplayer Stardew Valley have two variations:

1. Professions that affect item selling price apply to all players, as long as the player with that skill is online.
2. Professions that affect gameplay in other ways apply only to that player.

**Before 1.5.3**: When a player **places** a crab pot with either the Mariner or the Luremaster profession, the effect is tied to that crab pot. That means that the bonus will remain so long as the pot remains there, even if another player collects from it. However, if another player without the profession breaks the crab pot and replaces it, it will no longer have the effect from the profession.

**Since 1.5.3**: When a player **refills** a crab pot, their professions get applied to that pot.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @iBug -- I answered from memory of the mechanic and just reused the wording in the question haha.